Are there any editors for script command that allow to fix typos?
I want to record a gif with interaction of my Linux tool (REPL), but it's time consuming to make it perfect without any mistakes when I type the commands.
So I was wondering of using script command and then edit it later, but I will probably break the script if I try to edit it.
So are there any tools that allow to edit the session and timing from script command? Or maybe something that will allow me to write the code that will be automated in the shell with visual feedback?
I asked ChatGPT he suggested to use expect, but the output doesn't look good. It can automate a single executable (my program) but it will don't show the shell prompt, how I type the program name, and execute it.
ChatGPT also suggested to use asciinema, but it only animates a fixed text. And I want to animate the interaction with the shell.

Asciinema supports recording full interactions — anything you can record with script, you can record with Asciinema.
Asciinema recordings are easier to edit than script recordings; see this FAQ entry for details (it still involves manually editing a file, but it’s a JSON file and you shouldn’t need to tweak timings).
When recording terminal-based demos, I find it easier to prepare all the commands in a file, and then copy/paste them into the terminal! That avoids typos and even forcing watchers to wait for me to type commands in one character at a time.

Thanks, I don't copy/paste the commands from a file, because I want to have animation of typing. I need a closer look at asciinema.
